# Size problems with html2canvas after updating electron to 6.0.0

Tags: electron, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas to create images and export them to pdf in electron using jspdf.
With electron 2.0 everything worked fine, but when updating to electron 6.0 the canvas object that returns html2canvas of an element of the DOM has larger proportions (width and height).
Now I have to modify by testing the size of the PDF when I generate it (when creating the jspdf object).
Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Shoot, I'd really hoped someone had an answer for this.

I've discovered that the zoom factor of the page has a contributory impact on it. If I scale the window down to 80% zoom I don't get the jerking resize.

This tells me two things:

1. that the html2canvas renderer is not influenced by the zoom, and...
2. the scale factor aspect ratio that's producing the effect.

When I figure this out, I'll post it here to help those that follow (and possibly the OP, assuming he still cares some 6 months later).